# How to integrate visual captcha in jsf page with javascript of jquery

Tags: captcha

I am trying to integrate visual captcha in my jsf page. is there a link where i can see steps for doing it. i followed the below steps from visual captcha for jquery but it didn't work.

Initialization

Include jQuery library and jQuery version of the visualCaptcha front-end library into the HTML page:

Create a visualCaptcha container into the HTML page:

Initialize the captcha with the $( element ).visualCaptcha( options ) jQuery function that returns a jQuery object within the visualCaptcha object. It uses two parameters: element is a selector of a container for the visualCaptcha, options is an object of the visualCaptcha options:

var el = $( '#sample-captcha' ).visualCaptcha( {
    imgPath: 'img/',
    captcha: { numberOfImages: 5 }
} );

// use the following code to get the captcha object
var capthca = el.data( 'captcha' );